# VR+AR on mobile phone

Tags: android, ios, mobile, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I have web VR application with a-frame framework and it works fine in browser.
It is work as 3D on screen and as VR if you have VR on your PC.
I want to know what I have to do if I want to:

1) have it as 360, I mean that I can goes with phone arround my 3D model on the mobile screen over screen from camera what camera catch (like mixed reality)?

2) same as 1) but as real AR with something like google cardboard?

Ok,it is that simple. Exactly what I want for 1):

https://aframe.io/blog/arjs/

It gives You 1)
But as VR I don't see what my camera see.
It isn't AR, pure VR.

Answer (score 0):

My company has a product we call [Viro React](https://viromedia.com/viroreact/) which is a platform that enables developing for mobile VR (Cardboard, GearVR, Daydream, iOS Cardboard) and AR (ARKit for iOS and ARCore for Android).

It's built on React-Native which is React-based (Javascript library) but it runs on your device and you can then compile and ship your apps on iOS and Android app stores.

Best of all, we're free to use!

Check out our:

- [Website](https://viromedia.com/) to sign up for a key
- [Blog](https://blog.viromedia.com/) where we highlight some things you can do on our platform!
- [Github](https://github.com/viromedia/viro) where we have sample code and where you can file issues.