# Is it possible to build an AR App, with a VR display wrapper, for mobile devices, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

thanks kindly for your time and attention. I recognise this is a long shot but I'm hoping someone might be generous enough to relay some advice or guidance. I am in the beginning phases of researching how I might build an app for a mobile device, using javascript and related tools, libraries and packages. The concept for the app is that it will access the device camera, recognise faces, and overlay animated AR assets onto the device display. However, I want users to couple their phone with a wearable headset, and use the app through a split screen VR style display. I assume I'll need some sort of VR wrapper for the core AR application. At the moment, I am focussed primarily on the graphical display and UI aspects, so that I can build a proof-of-concept to test whether the idea is even viable. I recognise I may be misguided to attempt this in javascript rather than native mobile languages - if this is the case, I would welcome any opinions on the matter. I'm asking about javascript because that's what I know, basically.

Thus far, I've been reading about various libraries such as WebXR, Three.js and others. I assume I'll need to use React Native, though it's not easy to get a clear sense of whether I should even be trying to achieve what I want using javascript. I have no code to show as yet.

Additionally, I recognise there are similar questions already posted to the forum - for example, this one: [VR+AR on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360713/vrar-on-mobile-phone).
I haven't found any recent threads that address this specific set of requirements so I do apologise if I've missed something. If there is info on the forum, grateful if someone could point me to the relevant thread. At the very least, thanks for reading. Cheers, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Snap's Lens Studio extremely intuitive and powerful. It provides templates for feature recognition, tracking, and physics. It also provides advanced controls for custom creative. I would also expect it to receive future feature development support. It can be monetized.

...or do you want to expose yourself to more computer vision terminology and patterns? Try searching CodePen or CodeSandbox for features such as: MediaPipe, OpenCV, face detection webcam. But the overhead of a VR/AR app is probably best described in an O'Reilly book or John Carmack keynote speech. Topics like pupil distance, foot tracking, and predictive tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice, PartialFlavor. I sincerely appreciate it - cheers.